# Disable Submit Button and Enable Afterwards

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have a form created with a submit button. What i`m trying to accomplish is that when the button is clicked and the form starts to submit I want the button to be temporarily disabled and after the form has finished submitting to be enabled again.

I submit the form through a normal PHP form.

Any clue on how to do this?

Comment: How do you submit the form via ajax?

Comment: Look into the `disabled` attribute of form elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this in onClick listener of Submit button at top:

```
$('#submitBtn').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

And add this in successCallBack function and failureCallback function of ajax call:

```
$('#submitBtn').removeAttr('disabled');
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
You need to create a jQuery function on form post.
```

for example:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    $('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

Comment: And the removing of the `disabled`?

Comment: try this $('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled', false);

Answer (score 0):

Jquery [`PROP`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
$('#three').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
});
```

For finished submitting you need to get some valid output from the server to JS.Success handler in the AJAX.

and from there Use bellow code

```
$(this).prop('disabled', false);
```

[`DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/samithaHewawasam/pn98J/)

Answer (score 0):

may be this..

```
  $('input[type=submit]').click(function() {
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $(this).parents('form').submit();
        $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```
 <script>

     function disablebutton(id) {
         if (id != "") {
             document.getElementById(id).setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
         } else {
             document.getElementById(id).removeAttribute("disabled");
         }
     }

 </script>

 <form action="" method="post" onsubmit="disablebutton('btn2');
    return false;">
     <input type="submit" id="btn2" class="button" name="submit" value="submit"  />
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Also Try This

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type='submit']").attr("disabled", false);

    $("form").submit(function(){
      $("input[type='submit']").attr("disabled", true).val("Please wait...");
      return true;
    })
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add "disable" attribute on submit button, if that doesn't work try usin jQuery's prevendDefault()

Comment: It is `disabled`, `preventDefault()` (with a T) but that doesn't do the same.